# OnClientClick postback even though return false on ie 7

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, internet-explorer-7

Ive got ASP:Button on my page:

```
OnClientClick="return CheckTerms();" CssClass="submit" OnClick="BtnRegister_OnClick" />
```

OnClientClick I do js to check something and according to the check result I would like to proceed postback or not.

On all browsers it works (when false is returned from OnClientClick there is no postback) but situation is different on ie 7 where postback goes

any hints ?

thank You very much for help

for the sake of clarity here is the code that doesnt work either:

function CheckTerms() {
        return false;
    }

Here is how buttons are rendered:

IE

```
chrome:

<input type="submit" name="ctl00$plhMain$Register$btnRegister" value="??????????????????" onclick="return CheckTerms();" id="ctl00_plhMain_Register_btnRegister" class="submit">
```

Please notice that I use PIE.htc on my inputs but on button no.

what is this ? jQuery16100078065287469022415

Comment: In IE7 also it will work.check that you have any script error have in ie7 before return false

Comment: Please post the code of `CheckTerms()`.

Comment: @gruber can you show the markup generated on the page for the button in both IE7 and another browser that works (if different).

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that an error is being thrown in IE7, and when an error is thrown it doesn't return false, and it will continue on with the postback.  You probably used a method that's not supported in IE7, or that acts differently than intended.  Without the actual javascript method and any relevant markup I couldn't say for sure though.